# Troubling on pushing item on array that is stored in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, ionic2, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I have two ionic pages 1) Menu Items 2) Your Orders
In 'Menu Items' page there are list of  menu items from which each menu is selected and added which is then passed to 'Yours Order' page. From 'Menu Items' page I am sending each item as a JSON object then I am trying to push it on array  'orders' which is on 'Yours Order' page. Then, I am storing that array to LocalStorage. Here, for first item it works but when I try to enter next item, going back to Menu items page, The first one gets replaced and only the latest one is stored which I actually don't want. I want to push multiple items to order page. What can be the solution??

[This is handler in "Menu Items" page from where each item is sent to 'Yours Order' page.]

```
 handler: data => {
             this.orderItem = {'tableId':this.tableId, 'menuId': menuItemData.item_id, 'menuName': menuItemData.name, 'qty': data.qty,
              'rate': menuItemData.price, 'description': data.description};
             this.navCtrl.push(OrderpagePage, {'orderItem':this.orderItem});
          }
```

From here I have pushed items in localstorage.

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
   let temp = this.navParams.get('orderItem');
   if(this.localStorageService.get('order') == null){
     this.orders.push(temp);
     this.localStorageService.set('order', this.orders);
   } else {
     let length:any[] = JSON.parse(this.localStorageService.get('order'));
     console.log(length)
     let temp1 = length.push(temp)
     this.localStorageService.add('order', temp1)
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.push` returns the new length of the array, not a reference or copy of the array.  As noted in another answer, `add` does not exist.  Also, you seem to be mixing whether the stored value is a JSON string or a javascript type.  LocalStorage takes string values.

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
   const order = this.navParams.get('orderItem');
   const ordersString = this.localStorageService.get('order')
   const orders = typeof ordersString === 'string' 
       ? JSON.parse(ordersString) 
       : []

   orders.push(order)

   this.localStorageService.set('order', JSON.stringify(orders))
}
```

Comment: Actually, I was using push in both the cases but later I changed it just to test. My misunderstanding was on the type that local storage stores. Thanks !! Dave Meehan for your answer.

Comment: You might want to check the docs more closely than I did, the underlying LocalStorage browser object takes strings, but Angular might do the conversion for you both ways.

Comment: Can you provide me the link where the concept of LocalStorage is being made more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line in your else block to -

```
this.localStorageService.set('order', temp1)
```

There is no method such as **add()** in localStorageService, use **set()** instead, as you did in the if block. Hope that works!

Reference - http://gregpike.net/demos/angular-local-storage/demo/demo.html